# julia: Gadfly display plots from terminal

Tags: plot, terminal, cygwin, julia

I'm using `Gadfly` and running Julia v0.5.1 from Cygwin, and am having trouble plotting to an external window from terminal.v For example, when I try to build a simple plot from a file `test.jl` by running `$ julia test.jl`, my plot doesn't appear.

My file `test.jl` contains:

```
 Pkg.add("Gadfly")
 using Gadfly
 plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10))
```

What do I need to do to view the plot?

Comment: Is Julia a cygwin program ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean precisely, could you please clarify? I have both [Julia](https://julialang.org/!) and Cygwin installed in separate folders on my C drive.

Comment: Then Julia is likely not a cygwin program. Can you plot from windows CMD ?